# How to call other js method in Index.cshtml page button onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have added js file `bootstrap-notify.js` [file link](https://github.com/ashuthinks/bootstrap-notify/blob/master/dist/bootstrap-notify.js) which is having `Notify function` which generates notification dynamically.

I'm able to call that notify function on page load but when I try to execute it on button click getting error :`Uncaught TypeError: $.notify is not a function`

any clue why is it so?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function myfun() {
            debugger;
            $.notify({
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign',
                title: 'Bootstrap notify',
            message: 'Turning standard Bootstrap alerts into "notify" like notifications'
            }, { type:'success', delay: 1000, timer: 2000
            });
        }
    </script>

    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="myfun();">TEST</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please check whether you include jquery twice or not?

Comment: checked that too . interesting thing is when I put  `$.notify({` code outside myfun() it is working fine try it